# Which of the following collections of 3-vectors space [a,b,c] are vectors? The vectors with ab=0.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am struggling to see why ab = 0 is not a vector space.

If V = [0,b,c], it is a vector space and if V = [a,0,c], it is a vector space and if V = [0,0,c], it is a vector space, shouldn't it be that vector space with ab = 0 be a vector space also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A vector space must be closed under addition. So the union of two subspaces is not necessarily a vector space.

Comment: What is $(0,1,2)+(3,0,-5)$?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of your question is "Why isn't the set of vectors from $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ for which $ab=0$ a vector space?

The answer is that it isn't closed under vector addition:

$(1, 0, 0) + (0, 1, 0) = (1, 1, 0)$

and $1 \cdot 1 = 1 \neq 0$.

All the examples in your justification are indeed vector spaces, and you are right that if you take the union of all those sets you obtain $\{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : ab = 0\}$, but the union of two vector spaces is not necessarily a vector space, as this example demonstrates. I recommend [this](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/09%3A_Vector_Spaces/9.05%3A_Sums_and_Intersections) for more information about ways to combine two vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question